# How do I add an event listener to a button inside a tab navigator (flex 4.5)?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I have a tab navigator defined in MXML, with two tabs.
In each tab, I have some buttons. I have used ActionScript to add event listeners to all the buttons, and they work for the buttons that are visible (and in the currently "active" tab) when I load my Flex 4.5 AIR application.

However, I get an AIR error for the event listeners attached to the buttons in the second tab.
Here's the crucial part of the error:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

And when I test out my application, sure enough, there are no event listeners attached to the buttons in the second tab.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to set `creationPolicy`to 'all' on your TabNavigator. This is because, by default, Flex only initializes the screens that are actually visible. If you set your TabNavigator `creationPolicy` attribute to "all", all elements will be initialised, even if they are not visible.